# Implicit conversion issue in Scala

Tags: scala, type-inference, implicits

I'm improving the Scala support in Querydsl and I encountered the following issue. Here is a code snippet that illustrates the problem :

```
// framework types  
class RelationalPath[T]
class RelationalPathAdapter[T, R <: RelationalPath[T]](p: R) { def someMethod = {} }

// domain types
class User  
class QUser extends RelationalPath[User]

implicit def toAdapter[T, R <: RelationalPath[T]](p: R) = new RelationalPathAdapter[T,R](p)

val path = new QUser()

toAdapter(path).someMethod // DOESN'T COMPILE

path.someMethod // DOESN'T COMPILE
```

How to match a type in a implicit conversion in addition to it's type argument. I can match either separately, but not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this specific case, the following change works:

```
implicit def toAdapter[T, R <: RelationalPath[T]](p: RelationalPath[T] with R) = 
  new RelationalPathAdapter[T,R](p)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an implicit conversion issue, rather a type inference issue. When you call toAdapter(path), there is nothing implicit.

If you pass the type parameter, it works.

```
toAdapter[User, QUser](path).someMethod
```

It can even work with an implicit conversion :

```
 (path: RelationalPathAdapter[User, QUser]).someMethod
```

but of course, this is rather useless.

The proper way to write the implicit is

```
implicit def toAdapter[T, R[X] <: RelationalPath[X]](p: R[T]) 
  = new RelationalPathAdapter[T, R[T]](p)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Try this : val conv: RelationalPathAdapter[User,QUser] = toAdapter(path)

Comment: Still, it answers your original question, as you can do `path.someMethod`. But good point, the information about `QUser` is lost, you have only `RelationalPathAdapter[User, RelationalPath[User]]`. Alexey's solution it is then.

Comment: Yes, my question was not explicit enough. Thanks for your efforts though.